# Truncate NSString with a Name

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have got a NSString which will contain names. I'd like to truncate everything after the space except for the first letter.

An example

> @"David Campbell"

to

> @"David C"

Using this removes all of the lastName

> NSString *str = @"David Campbell";
>
> NSRange range = [str
> rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch];
>
> NSString *str2 = [str
> substringToIndex:range.location];

Please advice me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to `NSString *str2 = [str substringToIndex:range.location + 2];`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"David Campbell";
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *str2 = [str substringToIndex:(range.location + 1)];
```